# Caret featurePlot giving "object cannot be coerced" error

Tags: r, r-caret

Code that use to run:

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
data_set <- diamonds %>%
  filter(row_number() <= 1000) %>%
  select(carat, depth)
featurePlot(x = data_set[,-1], y = data_set[,1])
```

now fails with

```
Error in diff(as.numeric(y[ord])) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Below also fails:

```
featurePlot(x = as.data.frame(data_set[,-1]), y = as.data.frame(data_set[,1]))
```

But below works:

```
featurePlot(x = data_set$depth, y = data_set$carat)
```

Seeking a way to use sub setting by column number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is something going on with the `tibble` class---I've encountered something similar. Try the following. It works for me:

```
class(data_set) <- "data.frame"
featurePlot(x = data_set[,-1], y = data_set[,1])
```

You might want to file an issue on GitHub, because it is indeed strange that your second approach (which is very sensible) does not work. I can confirm that both approaches that you tried also generate the same errors for me.

Comment: @Matt Uh, okay? Mine's R 3.4.3 and same `caret` version. Are you saying that my solution doesn't work?

Comment: All good Kim. Just in case anyone wonders, I'm using R 3.5.1 and caret 6.0-80